# Bootstrap4 datetimepicker disable time Intervals on every Monday

Tags: bootstrap-4, momentjs, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am making an appointment system. I want to prevent appointments that are not on the opening hours.

```js
$('input.datetimepicker-input').datetimepicker({
  locale: '{{ eccube_config.locale }}',
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
  minDate: moment("{{minTime}}"),
  disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [moment().day("Monday").hour(0).minutes(0), moment().day("Monday").hour(9).minutes(30)]
  ]
});
```

It seems like the `disabledTimeIntervals` option doesn't support the day unit. If you also know how to use `disabledTimeIntervals` every day please help.

Comment: Try using the following code please: ```disabledTimeIntervals: [moment().day("Monday").hour(0).minutes(0), moment().day("Monday").hour(9).minutes(30)]```

Comment: @GillesHeinesch thanks for the advice. but I don't think it is working neither....